# Call angular function using .Net Framework

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, angular

I am using the FileWatcher in the .Net Framework, when has a change should send the file changed to my angular function, I tried using the post method to service and also to the component, didn't work on both cases.

The angular file is in a different folder, so was not able to call it using Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript, any suggestions?

```
public FileWatcher()
        {
            var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"c:\folder")
            {
                NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
                               | NotifyFilters.CreationTime
                               | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
                               | NotifyFilters.FileName
                               | NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                               | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                               | NotifyFilters.Security
                               | NotifyFilters.Size
            };

            watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
            watcher.Filter = "file.json";
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        private static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
         ///Call angular function
        }
```

on the angular

```
export class FileChanged{

  constructor() {}

  UpdateNewInformations(objFile: Any){
  ///updating informations
  }
}
```

If possible, I can also get the file changes directly from the angle.

Comment: It sounds like the technology you're looking for is "web sockets".  Overall it's pretty broad and you'll want to find some tutorials/examples on the subject, but in general this is the technology used to allow server-side code to push data to client-side code.  Failing that, the client-side code would need to initiate requests to the server in order to fetch new information, which is called "polling" when done at regular intervals.

Comment: Please add references or your code snippet to the question

Comment: @marcuse, is it good now?

Comment: @David I liked the idea, but doesn't seem the right approach for my problem, I am thinking about do the file watcher inside the angular, but I am not sure how to do it either

Comment: @PedroAzevedo: If the file is server-side then how is client-side code going to "watch" it?  Even the question title about trying to "call an Angular function" from server-side code somewhat implies a misunderstanding of how these components interact.  The server-side code and the client-side code run at different times and on different platforms.  They are connected by the HTTP protocol.  Any communication between them has to happen through that.

Comment: @David the file is not necessarily server-side. Agreed with you, there is a misunderstanding of implementation, but I am not able to fix this, I am trying to play with cards that I have haha

Comment: @PedroAzevedo: Well, client-side JavaScript doesn’t have the kind of file system access you’re looking for then.  A user needs to authorize access to a file.  And server-side code obviously can’t read the client file system, so why are you putting that part in server-side code?  It’s becoming decreasingly clear what functionality you’re even trying to build here.

Comment: @David Currently the angular code is running the application and making requests to the code behind.
the code behind just starting the executing of the web site, then just do something when the angular code call the API methods

Comment: @PedroAzevedo: That much sounds reasonable.  Any time the client-side code needs to fetch information from the server it can make an AJAX request.  Is that happening now?  What isn’t working?  How does the file system watcher enter the scenario and how do you expect it to watch a file that isn’t even on the server?

Comment: @David This file is provided by the client-side, then I will have to watch the file, so it has any change while the application is running, I will be able to handle it. 
The .Net Framework is been used as a library and has been called by HttpClient.
If there are any other information that may help with this problem just ask me

Comment: @PedroAzevedo: So the user uploads the file and it gets posted to the server, either by a form post or AJAX code (doesn't much make a difference), and the server saves that file to its file system?  Then what further processes are going to modify that file and what information needs to be sent to the client?  Does it need to be sent to the client immediately when it happens, or should it be available to the client in a future request (like the next time they visit the page)?

Comment: The file properties can be modified manually when this happens, the UI must be updated. immediately.
They are being executed on the same platform